# Why Is Anchor Tag Not Working After Ajax Refresh of HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, href

I've searched all afternoon...but am a bit confused by now.  Lots of information on this topic...but not specific to how I'm doing it.  I may be doing it incorrectly for this use case...but with no further ado...

My HTML...

```
  <div class="spacer282" id="upvote-count">
    <a href="{% url 'Suggestions:suggestion_upvotes' pk=suggestion_detail.id %}">{{ suggestion_detail.total_upvotes }}</a>
  </div>
```

My AJAX...

```
    $(document).on("click",'.button',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var $this = $(this);
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: $this.data("href"),
           dataType: "json",
           csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
           beforeSend: function(xhr) {
           xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
           },
           success: function(response){
             document.getElementById('upvote-count').innerHTML = response['total_upvotes'];
           },
        });
        return false;
    });
```

This works fine...but after the first replace...the anchor tag is no longer clickable...I know that generally I need to reset the listener for this event...but because it's an anchor tag...I can't quite work out the best way to handle this.

Per the request...this is being done via Django and JSON Response...when the user clicks a button I do a refresh of the {{ suggestion_detail.total_upvotes }} via JSON...

```
class SuggestionLikeView(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        suggestion = Suggestion.objects.get(pk=pk)
 
        is_upvote = False

        for upvote in suggestion.upvotes.all():
            if upvote == request.user:
                is_upvote = True
                break

        if is_upvote:
            suggestion.upvotes.remove(request.user)

        return JsonResponse({'total_upvotes': suggestion.total_downvotes,"message":"success"})
```

This is working fine...again when the replace happens....the anchor no longer works unless I click on the refresh page...then the anchor starts working again.

Comment: Does your ajax return html that has a href attribute?

Comment: Please add the tag for the framework you're using that implements `{%...}` and `{{...}}`

Comment: That anchor element looks like it's relying on a templating system of some kind.  Is that server-side?  What is the exact HTML you're adding to the DOM from `response['total_upvotes']`?  It's not clear to me how exactly you're updating the anchor.

Comment: Are you replacing the entire anchor tag rather than just the textContent of the anchor tag? As others have indicated, we cannot tell what templating system you're using or what your returned data look like.

Comment: @Daedalus I am simply replacing the {{ suggestion_detail.total_upvotes }} via a JSONRESPONSE.  The number is updated....and that works....but the anchor tag gets rendered useless unless I refresh the page.  If I manually refresh the page...the anchor tag starts working again.

Comment: @SteveSmith If you're replacing the entire anchor tag with non-anchor html... Then of course it stops working. As is clear from your js, you target the `div` with id `upvote-count`... and then replace its content, the anchor, with the upvote-count, like you said.  The anchor doesn't work because there is no anchor anymore.

Comment: @Daedalus So the manual refresh that I'm doing is reactivating the hard coded HTML...it just that the REFRESH is only replace the {{ suggestion_detail.total_upvotes }}...that's what you're saying?

Comment: @SteveSmith No.  With this line: `document.getElementById('upvote-count').innerHTML = ...`, you target the container element of the anchor tag.  You then replace content of that container - the anchor tag.  There is no anchor tag anymore at this point.  You need to target the anchor, not its container, if you want to update the vote count but keep the anchor usable.

Comment: @Daedalus Thanks for the pointer.  So if I add an ID to the anchor tag...then replace the contents of that instead of the upvote-count...that should work?

Comment: @SteveSmith Yes.  Either that or `document.querySelector('#upvote-count a').innerHTML = ...`.

Comment: @Daedalus  Thanks again for taking the time to point this out to me.  I was pretty lost.  Your explanation makes perfect sense.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As Daedalus point out to me....I needed to move my replace from the div to the anchor portion of my HTML....

```
<div class="spacer282" id="upvote-count">
    <a href="{% url 'Suggestions:suggestion_upvotes' pk=suggestion_detail.id %}" id="upvote-url">{{ suggestion_detail.total_upvotes }}</a>
  </div>
```

And then updating this line of code...

```
   document.getElementById('upvote-url').innerHTML = response['total_upvotes'];
```

Did the trick.